# Need or not need to update state form prev state? React

Tags: reactjs, use-state

If I was setting the value of a state variable by a number but it was not dependent on the prev value, would I need to update based on prev state?

i.e

```
const [value, setValue] = React.useState<number>(7);

const handleClick = () => {
   setValue(30);
}
```

would I need to handle the prev value in the handle click ? this is not a counter or anything.

Comment: Try with `setValue((prev) =>  prev + 30);`

Comment: It could be updated without basing on the prev state, if you just want to set the new value

Comment: If your next state does not depend on the previous state then you don't need to pass a callback. Though you could `setValue(() => 30)` for example for readability `const reset = () => 30;` and then `setValue(reset)`. What you should NOT do is `setValue(value + 30)`.

Comment: `Value + 30` will add 30 to the value even `setValue((prev) =>  prev + 30);` will add 30 to the value

Comment: @YuryTarabanko add as answer so I can accept it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your next state does not depend on the previous state then you don't need to pass a callback. `setValue(30)` is perfectly fine.

Though you could `setValue(() => 30)`. Or for readability and self-documenting purpose you can define `const reset = () => 30;` and then use it in the component `setValue(reset)`.

What you should NOT do is `setValue(value + 30)`.